# Automatic login multiple web application

Tags: security, web-applications, single-sign-on

I have a web application inside which there are multiple other web applications. To use them user need to authenticate itself by entering username password.  I want once user logs into my application it should automatically logged in other application.

I don’t want to keep same username and password for every application but this will be my final resort.

I can ask user to authenticate itself for the first time and after that my application should be able to do it.

What possible approach /options I have in this scenario.

My application use javascript at client side.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to create something like [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/) authentication system. You can use [cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to save data in it. e.g You can create Login cookie for about 3 days life time. It means that your users can login for about 3 days. Cookies are not safe (specially for storing important datas like passwords). To secure cookies you can hash your data. But even doing this the user can delete cookies from browser; Or if user clean its browser history on exit, cookies will be deleted.

---

Here web have code for creating cookies:

```
HttpCookie loginCookie = new HttpCookie("LoginCookie");
```

After that you can set cookie expires (life time):

```
loginCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
```

And you can insert data in it:

```
loginCookie.Values.Add("password", "Hashed value of password here");
```

---

For **Logout**: Create button and set this code in Click event:

```
 Response.Cookies["LoginCookie"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

---

Its better to use sessions. They are more safe. How to create sessions:

```
 Session["Password"] = "Hashed value of password here";
```

And in **logout button** (Remove all sessions):

```
Session.Abandon();
```

Removing specific session:

```
Session.Remove("Password");
```